# Code reads entire database. How can I limit it?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have project app written in flutter and I get too many readings. I spotted where the problem is but I don't know how to limit fetching entire database when getComments method was triggered. So this is my code:

```
 Future<List<CommentModel>> getComments(String sharingID) async {
    DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> documentSnapshot =
        await firestore.collection('comments').doc(sharingID).get();
    Map<String, dynamic>? commentsMap = documentSnapshot.data();
    List<CommentModel> commentList = [];
    if (commentsMap != null) {
      for (Map<String, dynamic> element in commentsMap.values) {
        commentList.add(CommentModel.fromMap(element));
      }
    }
    commentList.sort((a, b) => a.commentDate.compareTo(b.commentDate));
    return commentList;
  }
```

and I use this function to match comments with sharingId:

```
Future<void> getComments(String sharingID) async {
    commentList = await firebaseDbService.getComments(sharingID);
    print("$commentList");
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

So can anybody help me to avoid reading entire database when new comment was added or refreshed the page.
Thanks

I've tried the code below:

```
Future<List<CommentModel>> getComments(String sharingID, {int? limit}) async {
  Query<Map<String, dynamic>> commentsQuery = firestore.collection('comments').doc(sharingID).collection('comments');
  if (limit != null) {
    commentsQuery = commentsQuery.limit(limit);
  }
  QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> querySnapshot = await commentsQuery.get();
  List<CommentModel> commentList = [];
  for (QueryDocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> documentSnapshot in querySnapshot.docs) {
    Map<String, dynamic>? commentMap = documentSnapshot.data();
    if (commentMap != null) {
      CommentModel commentModel = CommentModel.fromMap(commentMap);
      commentList.add(commentModel);
    }
  }
  commentList.sort((a, b) => a.commentDate.compareTo(b.commentDate));
  return commentList;
}
```

```
Future<void> getComments(String sharingID) async {
    commentList = await firebaseDbService.getComments(sharingID, limit: 1);
    print("$commentList");
    notifyListeners();
}
```

New data was not displaying in the app. I was able to see in firebase but not in the app.

I just don’t want load every comment from the database when it refreshes or every time getComment function is called

Comment: You shared 6 snippets of code, and it is not clear which one is not working as expected. The `firestore.collection('comments').doc(sharingID).get()` call in the first snippet loads exactly one document. The next 3 snippets seem irrelevant, and I'm not sure how the final 2 snippets relate. --- Please edit your question to share exactly one code snippet that reproduces the problem. I recommend reading [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more hints that make it more likely someone can answer.

Comment: instead of limiting your fetched data with hard-code, I suggest you learn about 'pagination', this will allow you to load more sets of data when required

Comment: I’ve updated my post. Left only relevant codes.

Comment: I’ll look into pagination. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: What is the exact code that you think it reads the entire database?

Comment: I tested the first one read the entire data base